# Телеграмм бот отправляет одну и ту же фотографию через random.choice, хотя в списке, много фото. Как это пофиксить?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, случайные-числа

Всем привет, решил добавить в бота функцию отправки рандомного сообщения, но почему-то при запуске бота и выполнении команды, приходит одна и та же фотография. Погуглив, нашёл код, который всё фиксит, но не помогло (библиотеки установлены). При перезапуске бота, он выбирает другую фотку и отправляет только её. Подскажите, что можно решить с этим:

```
picts = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
tak = random.choice(picts)
random_message = lambda: random.choice(picts)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'давай':
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, tak)
```

Comment: picts сначала список, потом picts - элемент этого списка, его он и отправляет... переименуйте переменную

Comment: исправил, ситуация не изменилась, всё так-же отправляет одну и ту же картинку. Вот код:

picts = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
tak = random.choice(picts)
random_message = lambda: random.choice(picts)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'дай картинку':
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, tak)

Comment: пожалйста используйте кнопку Править под вашим вопросом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно вызывать выбор рандома внутри функции. Так как сейчас у вас единожды выбирается рандом и дальше одно и тоже возвращает.

Псевдокод для запуска из консоли.

```
import random

picts = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']

def send_text(message):
    if message == 'давай':
        tak = random.choice(picts)
        print(tak)


send_text('давай')
send_text('давай')
send_text('давай')

>>> 3
>>> 2
>>> 7
```