# Какую функцию random надо использовать для списков?

Tags: python, discord.py

Код:

```
@bot.command()
async def ball(ctx):
    await ctx.send(role)
roles = ["конечно", "скорей всего нет", "точно нет!", "шар не уверен :thinking:", "шар ничего не видит", "определенно ДА!", "шар в замешательстве, попробуйте еще", "все слишком мутно.. пропробуйте позже", "частично да" ]
role = random.choice(roles)
```

Я напечатал список, моя цель была случайный выбор фрагмента(тип: str)
Но я не знаю, какой подходит для этих списков(пишу для дискорда чтобы пользователь вводил команду, и выбиралось случайное из списка)
Но есть одно но, когда кто то вводит команду, надо чтобы каждый раз было разное, а при random.choice после запуска кода при вводе команды оно выбирает только один раз, и чтобы было другое надо перезапускать код.

[image]

Comment: надо перенести `random.choice` в хендлер, у вас оно, видимо, при запуске выбирает

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1231566/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-random-choice-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8

Answer (score 1):

перенесите `random.choice(roles)` в начало обработчика команды !ball

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, написать как должно выглядеть? Я не очень понял

Comment: извиняюсь за игнор. https://katb.in/azoqodimehu